# Sending data to the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem with sending the entered data to the database using the php and html form post method. When I click submit, only the header is sent to the database, and everything else throws an error
Note: Undefined Index: Image
Note: Undefined index: Information
Note: Indeterminate index: Price

My code
https://prnt.sc/126k1fi
Error
https://prnt.sc/126k2a3

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots to your code and traceback message, please add the code to your question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bro your html code tags having different name and you get the POST data with different name. Just do the below changes in your html and try.

**NOTE**: [Please study the basic PHP from here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/index.htm)

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" required />
   <input type="number" name="price" placeholder="Price" required />
                               ^
   <input type="file" id="myFile" name="image" />
                                          ^
   <input type="text" name="info" placeholder="Info" required />
                             ^    
   <input type="submit" name="add" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: If you got the correct answer, please accept my answer.